# "Network is unreachable", github, bitbucket is not working

Tags: networking, curl, github

The output of `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:0e:74:43:8e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:742760 (742.7 KB)  TX bytes:742760 (742.7 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b2:01:81:d7:78:3f  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:b7:e2:7a:cd:65  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f6b7:e2ff:fe7a:cd65/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:106677 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:79355 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:113695485 (113.6 MB)  TX bytes:13547631 (13.5 MB)
```

The output of `ip route`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.5  metric 9 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122
```

When I try to do `curl -I github.com`
output is

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to github.com port 80: Network is
>   unreachable

While git cloning I get this even while git push `443 failed: Network is unreachable`

Comment: can you ping github.com ? google.com ? nsa.gov ?

Comment: Is your wireless router connected to the internet? Can you ping or traceroute bitbucket.org? Can you ping 131.103.20.167 (the IP I get for bitbucket.org)?

Comment: @Paul I converted your answer to a comment but please don't do that again. If you don't have the rep to comment, then don't comment. Stick around a bit and you'll get it in no time, it only takes 50 to comment (that's 10 upvotes on questions or 5 on answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the **vast** assumption that the rest of your networking is ok, (i.e. can route traffic to your default gateway, you can resolve and reach outside hosts, etc) and that you are only seeing these kind of problems for one site, github.com, then it is possible that you have an encountered a problem on their end.

If the above assumption is not correct, or you are seeing wide spread outages when reaching external hosts then I would suggest some basic troubleshooting, starting with layer 1 (is it plugged in) and going upwards.

It is possible that you may be seeing some of the minor variations on github.com quality of service. Github is big and getting bigger every day. Here are a few resources for monitoring their network uptime:

1. [Overall Status Averages](https://status.github.com)
2. [Historical Uptime and Event Logs](https://status.github.com/messages/2015-07-01)

Also don't be afraid to `traceroute` or `mtr` the connection from your devices to github. Do be aware that github [has undergone malicious attacks](https://github.com/blog/1981-large-scale-ddos-attack-on-github-com) in recent months as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. My issue was the subnet mask. It was set to 255.0.0.0 by mistake.  Github's ip at the present time starts with 192.30.x.x. The system thought github was a part of my lan.

Since everything else worked the intermittent weirdness made it look like the problem was on github's side. I googled it, got this post and followed along with OP, saw my mask and went 'that's not right...'.

Switching the mask to 255.255.255.0 fixed things up for me. So I'm leaving this here for the next person.

Comment: In the OP's situation, the netmask really is `255.255.255.0`